# How to pad integer printing with leading zeros?

Tags: c, arrays, integer, printf

So i have to make kinda like a timer and this has to be a string and it has to have a 0 before if it is smaller than ten so like 00,01,02...09,10,11 so all numbers are 2 digits. But I've ran into a problem and i cant seem to solve it. And I need to have it kinda like so no ctime or not to turn it at all into a string.

I've tried a couple of times also with the decompiler tools but I see that the main problem is in position 4 and 7. I think that there may be something wrong with the code blocks compiler, but i am not so sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char tostring[9]={};
    int timer=6588;
    int hours=0;
    int minutes=0;
    int seconds=0;

    hours=timer/3600;
    minutes=(timer%3600)/60;
    seconds=(timer%3600)%60;
    //printf("%i:%i:%i",hours,minutes,seconds);

    if(hours<10){
        tostring[0]=(char)0;
        tostring[1]=(char)hours;
    }else{
        tostring[0]=(char)(hours/10);
        tostring[1]=(char)(hours%10);
    }
    tostring[2]=':';
    if(minutes<10){
        tostring[3]=(char)0;
        tostring[4]=(char)minutes;
    }else{
        tostring[3]=(char)(minutes/10);
        tostring[4]=(char)(minutes%10);
    }
    tostring[5]=':';
    if(seconds<10){
        tostring[6]=(char)0;
        tostring[7]=(char)seconds;
    }else{
        tostring[6]=(char)(seconds/10);
        tostring[7]=(char)(seconds%10);
    }
    tostring[8]='\0';
    printf("%s",tostring);
    return 0;
}
```

i expect the output to be 01:49:48, but nothing comes out, just blank. What would be a solution to solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tostring[0]=(char)0;` does not write the character representation of `0` into tostring[0].  It writes a zero.  You want `tostring[0] = '0'`, with single quotes.  And similarly, to write the character representation of a single digit, you can write `tostring[1] = '0' + hours` (If hours is 5, then '0' + 5 is the character value used to represent `5` in the local character set.  Thankfully, it was standardized long ago that those representations should be sequential so that sort of thing works.) But, unless the point of this exercise is to avoid using printf, you should really just use printf.

Comment: Depends on the character set.  On my machine, '0' is 48, so the difference between '0' and 0 is .... 48 !  Character 'a' is represented by 97, `A` is 65, `0` is 48, and `\0` is 0.  (Those numbers can vary, but '\0' is always 0)

Comment: Thanks that solved it but I'm interested what is the difference between `tostring[0] = (char)0;` and `tostring[0] = '0';`. Cause in theory they should be the same.

Comment: No, they shouldn't be the same.  They are radically different.  `'0'` is the representation of the character `0` in the local character set (eg, the integer value 48), while `0` is the literal `0`, more commonly represented by `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this, why don't you print integers with fixed width and padded with `0`?

Something like

```
 printf("%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds);
```

should do the job.

Explanation for the format specification `%02i`:

- `%` start of conversion specifier
- `0` leading `0`s will be used for padding (if the actual length of the value is less than the minimum field width)
- `2` value of the minimum field width.
- `i` integer

Edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int timer=6588;
    int hours=0;
    int minutes=0;
    int seconds=0;

    hours=timer/3600;
    minutes=(timer%3600)/60;
    seconds=(timer%3600)%60;

    printf("%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution, but it would probably be helpful to add an explanation of why the OP's attempt does not work as intended.